# React Navigation infinite stack / dynamic stack

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack

I would like to realise an infinite stack with react navigation, that means I would need a dynamic stacknavigator where I can push in a unlimited number of screens (a maximum of 20 screens would be enough). You can imagine this like in the amazon app where you can click on a related product in the product details and it shows you another product details screen where you can do the same thing.

Does anyone of you has an idea how to do that ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be done with `react-navigation`

Instead of using `this.props.navigation.navigate('ScreenName')` you can use `this.props.navigation.push('ScreenName')`

You would probably want to pass some sort of description to the screen so that it knows what to render you can do that by passing params

`this.props.navigation.push('ScreenName', { key: productId })`

You would just have to set up a few template screens that could then be populated by the parameters that you pass to them.

You can see more about the different functions that react-navigation has here
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-prop.html#navigator-dependent-functions

Here is a snack showing it working https://snack.expo.io/@andypandy/infinite-navigation

In the snack I pass a position and date, you can see these update as each screen is pushed onto the stack. Pressing `Go Back` goes back one place on the stack.

Comment: Thanks that's what I was looking for!

Comment: What about performance and RAM? I think that if we need an infinite Stack we will have to pop some items from the head when the stack size is high. For example, I am doing something similar in my app, and when I push multiple screens the performance is really bad on my iPhone 6 (normal device)